# Devi ganga journey

Tags: puranas, devi, ganga

Hey guys I'm looking for information on devi ganga whole journey from her creation in Goloka and breakdown of the journey to earth.

What purana or scriptures will be good. And even better if there is a poet/bhajan of the kathas. Like those found of Lord rama katha writing by saints like tulsidas or bansidar.

Comment: Srimad Valmiki Ramayana covers whole information about Devi Ganga. There are 2-3 sarga in bAla khanda where the whole story is narrated. I might be able to say exact sarga number when I get back to home.

Comment: Check Sarge 40-42 in Bala Kanda of Srimad Valmiki Ramayana for the complete story